# Find Records With No Matching Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I know the title of this is ambiguous and this questions has probably been asked before, but I don't know how to summarise my question so as to be able to search for it or write a better title!  It's probably simple but it keeps coming up and I can't get my head around it.  So here's an example:

Let's say I have this table `Lunch`:

[image: Who had what for lunch?]

If I want to query everyone who had an apple with their lunch it's easy, I just use

```
SELECT [Name] FROM [Lunch] WHERE [Lunch Item] = 'Apple' GROUP BY [Name]
```

But what if I want to get a list of people who did NOT have an apple with their lunch?  If I use

```
SELECT [Name] FROM [Lunch] WHERE [Lunch Item] <> 'Apple' GROUP BY [Name]
```

the results will still include people who DID have an apple, because they also had something else which wasn't an apple.

As I say, I feel like this must be a simple query, but I don't know what the syntax would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer approaching these problems using aggregation:

```
select [name]
from lunch
group by name
having sum(case when [lunch item] = 'Apple' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

This structure is quite generalizable.  If you want someone who has apples and grapes, but not oranges, you can do:

```
select [name]
from lunch
group by name
having sum(case when [lunch item] = 'Apple' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when [lunch item] = 'Oranges' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when [lunch item] = 'Grapes' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: For some reason I can't get this to work. I understand the principle behind it, but when I try using COUNT in the SELECT statement, or LIKE in the CASE clause it seems to break it. How, for example, would I adapt this to return the number of people who did not have a lunch item containing the letters 'pple'?

Comment: No, I take it back.  I can get your first example to work, but if I change the SELECT statement to SELECT COUNT it returns NULL.  Can't imagine why!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a table for people:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    people
WHERE   name NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  name
        FROM    lunch
        WHERE   lunchItem = 'apple'
        )
```

If you don't:

```
SELECT  name
FROM    lunch
EXCEPT
SELECT  name
FROM    lunch
WHERE   lunchItem = 'apple'
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be SELECT DISTINCT name? Or will EXCEPT remove duplicates in the first query?

Comment: My real-life scenario actually does involve two tables, and the first example looks like just what I need, except that I can't get it to work. The query parses ok but returns no results.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: `EXCEPT` removes duplicates

Comment: @PhilipStratford: probably people in you model are fond of apples?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this if you want yo use a group by clause. If you just want a list of people there are many other ways aswell.

```
SELECT [Name]
FROM [Lunch]
GROUP BY [Name]
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN [Lunch Item] = 'Apple' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 --people who had a total amount of 0 apples for lunch
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a third approach, because why not!

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name 
FROM Lunch L
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Lunch WHERE Name = L.Name AND [Lunch Item] = 'Apple')
```

Answer (score 1):

using `NOT EXISTS` approach

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Lunch a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT  1
    FROM    Lunch b
    WHERE   a.Name = b.Name AND
            b.Item = 'Apple'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT IN` operator to exclude all those who had Apple.

```
SELECT * FROM Lunch
WHERE Name NOT IN ( SELECT Name
                    FROM Lunch
                    WHERE LunchItem ="Apple"
                   )
```

I don't think `GROUP BY` clause is required.